# ASP.Net Postback after jQuery load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I'm currently loading a separate URL into a DIV on my page when a user clicks a button. When this happens, the next time my page needs to postback, the postback goes to the separate URL that I loaded in the DIV.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it from posting back to a different page?

Here are the steps:

1. User loads main page
2. User clicks a button to call the jQuery load method to load HTML from a separate URL
3. User causes postback on main page
4. The page is posted-back to the URL of the separate page instead of the main page

Some sample code:

When the user clicks the button

```
$('#anchorViewResourceCalendar').unbind('click');
$('#anchorViewResourceCalendar').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var webUserID = $('select.ddlResource').val();
    var date = $('select.ddlMonth').val();
    if (webUserID > 0) {
        var calendarContainer = $('#divResourceCalendarContentContainer');
        calendarContainer.html('<div>Please wait...</div>');
        $('#divResourceCalendarContainer').dialog('open');

        calendarContainer.load('../ViewUserCalendar.aspx?ViewWebUserID=' + webUserID + '&Date=' + date);
    }
});

// Code for when the dialog opens/closes (since I'm emptying out the containing div)
$('#divResourceCalendarContainer').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: '1050',
    height: '850',
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

        $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
            $('#divResourceCalendarContainer').dialog('close');
        })
    },
    close: function () {
        $('#divResourceCalendarContentContainer').empty(); // this removes anything added by jQuery on the page so it's back to it's original state of when the page was initially loaded
    }
});
```

Comment: Inspect the page DOM before and after calling jquery load. How many `form` tags are there and what are their action urls?

Comment: Before the load, I only have one from my main page. After the load, I have two form controls. So, I've modified the closing of the dialog that opens to clear out the #divResourceCalendarContainer element so there is only one form when the dialog is closed).

Then when I cause a postback, same issue. Even if I look at the action url for the original form after all of that has happened (but before the postback), the action URL still points to the original page.

Comment: I don't know what "I've modified the closing of the dialog that opens to clear out ..." means.

Comment: It means that contains the div that's being loaded with content from the other page is displayed, it's displayed in a dialog (notice the $('#XXXXXX').dialog('open'). So, when this dialog is closed, I empty the calendar container so the form that was added from the other page is completely removed from main page. I've added the other JS I'm using to do this

Comment: Is the dialog form outside the other form tag?

Comment: Initially it is. Here are the steps: 1) Dialog is empty and inside form  2) Dialog is created through jQuery and moved outside form  3) Dialog is opened and moved inside form  4) Dialog inner div is loaded from separate page with jQuery  5) Dialog is closed and emptied  6) Dialog is moved back outside the form   7) Any postback on the page is directed to the wrong URL

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML to give a clear picture of the DOM structure and to give something to test against.  Also add any other javascript that is used on the page.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Web Forms, not MVC. If that's the case, I would think that loading a full ASPX page into a div will also load its form and JS payload. Therefore, those elements are conflicting with the "main" page and causing the odd postback. Even though you are removing the dialog div when closed, it sounds like something is getting mucked up.

Comment: Suspected on line $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

Comment: Miles as @BateTech has said, please add the generated HTML to the question. I'd also be interested to know what the console says when the AJAX load is fired...

Comment: Please Provide complete HTML of this scenario.... both before and the ajax load is called because only JS is not enough to track the root cause.

Comment: you are saying that the postback goes to another page. does the postback goes to page which you loaded into the Div using ajax, if so then there must be a form in the div and you are firing postback from inside the div, if this is not the case then please provide some clear picture of the question.